# Background image doesn't show on some mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I launched a website a few days ago in which I set an image as background in a banner on the index page.
The image shows fine on all desktop browsers and also on most phones, but one of my friends just commented that it doesn't show on her phone. I have no idea why.
It's my first time making a website, so there's still a lot of things I'm not sure about.
The website is called [www.mitsi.be](http://www.mitsi.be)
Here's the code I used:

HTML:

```
    <main>
      <section class="index-banner">
        <div class="leeg">
        </div>
        <small> Copyright &copy; 2021 Jeanne De Preter. All Rights Reserved</small> 
      </section>
 </main>
```

CSS:

```
   .index-banner {
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
   background-image: url('images/onderdrukkingsposter.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   text-align: end;
}

.leeg  {
   height: 92%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 410px) {
   .leeg  {
       height: 95%;
   }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
   .wrapper { 
       width: 1000px;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .index-banner {
       height: 600px;
   }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
   .index-banner {
       height: 980px;
   }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your image is quite large (24MB) - don't know if that is causing the problem but probably you should look at serving smaller versions for smaller devices anyway. Also, small point, but on some mobile OSs (e.g. IOS) 100vh is larger than the initial viewport height and your calc does not take enough off so the bottom copyright notice is not shown unless the user scrolls.

Comment: Well for starters, your background image is 6000 x 4000 px, and 11.6 MB large. That is WAY too large. You need to optimize that image for web use.

Comment: Reduce the size of the image, to further improve the performance, you can also have a smaller image for smaller devices.